# Python setting SQL query parameters only if included in GET request

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have an AWS lambda python function which hits a PostgreSQL database using psycopg2. There are many optional query string parameters so I never know the exact structure of the query.

What I want to do is check if a particular parameter exists. If it does than I set a variable to that parameter to be used in my query.  If the parameter was not included in the query string than I want to set my variable to something else.

Here is what I am trying to run currently:

```
location = event['queryStringParameters']['location'] or '*'

    postgres_get_query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  location = %(location)s"
    cursor.execute(postgres_get_query, {'location': location})
```

When I try to run this without passing the location query string parameter I get `KeyError: 'location'`.  I understand this error is because `event['queryStringParameters']['location']` does not exist. What I want to happen when that particular statement is false the variable assertion should move to the or statement similar to how javascript functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by first setting the default of the location variable to `None` and then updating it if a particular query string is passed in.

```
location = None
if event['queryStringParameters'].get('location'):
        location = event['queryStringParameters'].get('location')
```

Next my query just needs to be updated to ignore situations where `location` remains null.

```
postgres_get_query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (location = %(location)s OR %(location)s IS NULL)"
```

What this does is it returns all records where

Comment: You really dont seem to know how SQL ORs work.  This will always return records where location is NULL, regardless of whether you have a location specified or not.

Comment: @JLPeyret, That isn't the case with my query. I have tested it and the query works as expected.

Comment: To elaborate, when a location is provided the query returns ONLY records that match that location. If no location is provided the query returns all records. This happens because the condition `%(location)s IS NULL` evaluates to `TRUE` when no location is provided.

Answer (score -1):

Neither Python nor SQL is Javascript... you have to build your query conditionally.

```
location = event['queryStringParameters'].get('location')
postgres_get_query = "SELECT * FROM table "
if location:
    postgres_get_query += " WHERE  location = %(location)s"
```

If you have multiple possible criteria you will need to use something like `criterias.append("location = %(location)s")` and then `" AND ".join(criterias)` while keeping track of the WHERE.  Be generous with spaces, SQL doesn't mind them except when they are missing.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am misunderstanding but I don't think this answers my question at all.  I am able to get the `location` string parameters when location is passed as an argument.  What I want to do is set the location variable to something else ('*') if there is no locations query string parameter passed.

Comment: what purpose does that serve, query-wise?  is there an actual location called `*`?

Comment: in which case use `event['queryStringParameters'].get('location','*')` instead of your first line.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: In SQL databases the '*' is a wild card symbol so running `GET * FROM ...` is equivalent to saying GET all FROM.

Comment: @tdammon no it's not, not in the criteria.  `%` is the `*`-equivalent wildcard and it has to be used with `LIKE`, not `=`.  And, honestly, this whole sql issue has very very little to do with your KeyError.

Comment: The main issue though isn't the KeyError.  The KeyError is expected when I do not pass in a `location` query string.  But what I want to happen is to have my location variable update to a default value whenever that KeyError occurs.

Comment: Since you seem to know so much I’ll leave you to it.